# How do I create transferable dll's for a specific website functionality?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

VS2013 update 5, MVC5 using Areas

I have a stand-alone function programmed for a website.  The functionality is a specific user interface to collect survey responses in a particular way.  It has several controllers, a model and a group of views.  The functionality is completely contained in an Area of the project, except for the Shared _Layout file that provides the main menu for consistency.

'Is it possible for me to' / 'how do I' compile this Area into a single or set of .dll file(s) that I could then add conveniently to other websites?  I'm assuming creating something for transfer/download is very standard functionality.  For example, I used Elmah.MVC for this site.  What I want to do is pretty much create a package that can be downloaded in a similar way to how we integrate Elmah.MVC into a site. (Be certain I'm not talking about creating error logging software, I'm only using Elmah.MVC as an example of software that is easily integrated into other website applications.)

I've never compiled any website functionality into a .dll(s) for use elsewhere and would appreciate either some specific guidance, or perhaps what would be easier is to provide a link with a good step by step tutorial or explanation for how to do this.  Most of what I've found on the web describes bits and pieces of doing this, but it's not enough for me to feel confident with it.

It seems to me there are a lot of 'moving parts' to taking a particular piece of an MVC application and turning it into something that is easily added to other projects.

A particular issue I don't quite grasp is the difference in downloaded packages between getting code and getting just the .dll(s).  For instance, when I download an MVC5 site, I get controllers, models and views, but when I download Elmah I get a .dll and no code files.  Also, I do understand the concept of transforms, but I'm just struggling right now with even getting from my programmed application into a 'package' regardless of the transforms that make it easy to integrate into another website.

These are just some of my questions I have about how to perform this particular process in developing deliverable and/or shareable software.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is create a portable MVC Area project. A Portable Area is a set of reusable multi page functionality can be dropped into an application to provide rich functionality without having to custom build functionality that is literally the same in every application. An MVC Portable Area is really just a dll that contains the views, controllers, scripts, etc… needed to use in a website that is either a Web Forms website or an MVC website. A developer can use them for a reusable widget or a complete engine. I have actually used them for both. Here is a link with some basic info to get started. http://elegantcode.com/2012/04/06/mvc-portable-areas/

Comment: Sorry for long delay in responding.  I followed the link; long post so I'll have to study but looks promising.  However, what did the first commenter mean when he said 'This seems very, very brittle...'?  Also, is there a better/more accepted way to put together functionality in a package for reuse?  Why is the Area method you described not liked?  It seemed OK to me, but then I don't have enough experience to really judge.

Comment: This is a well known practice for MVC to use areas, Everyone has opinions but the portable-area is the way to go for your needs. Do some research on MVC areas as well as portable areas. you will see allot of people have different ways of doing things. Here is another link for you to look at. http://stevemichelotti.com/mvc-portable-areas-enhancement-ndash-embedded-resource-controller/